# Import spreadsheet(excel) , retaining special characters like exponent, subscript, superscript in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, exponent, roo-gem

We are importing an excel sheet into database in an Rails application, using Roo Gem. But it is ignoring cell format (superscript, subscript) like 5<sup>4</sup>, Mathematical symbols like <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> etc and importing it as plain text like 54 and 1/2. Is there any way we can import data retaining format of these cell/text?

Comment: The question is, which characters are this? Is it 5⁴ (5 followed by Unicode x2074) or is it 54 where the 4 is formatted as superscript? Is it ½ (ASCII xBD) or is it 1/2 where 1 is formatted as superscript and 2 is formatted as subscript? If ever the latter, as I suspect, then the data should come as 54 and 1/2 and then you have to get the cell's character format from excel somehow. So the question changes to: How to get the cell's character format from Excel?

Comment: Thanks Axel. Correct. It is the format, I need. I have mixed cell format with ASCII, which caused confusion.

Comment: OK, seems as if none of the Ruby gems already provides this feature. So if this is really important for you, then you should think in another direction. Apache POI can do this and seems as if it has a Ruby binding feature: http://poi.apache.org/poi-ruby.html. Using native Apache POI, I can help. But I've never used this with Ruby.